# MySQL twice update with one command

Tags: mysql

In the below `Update` command i want to set all `delay` field to `0` and an `id` of `2` must be update to `1`

[image]

```
UPDATE `tsms_entry_exit` 
         SET `delay`=( 
                      CASE `delay`  
                           WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                      END
                     )
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Otherwise:

```
UPDATE `tsms_entry_exit` 
         SET `delay`=0
WHERE user_id = 1;

UPDATE `tsms_entry_exit` 
         SET `delay`=0
WHERE user_id = 1 AND id = 2
```

How do i update twice in one update command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand very well, might be you want this

```
UPDATE `tsms_entry_exit` 
         SET `delay`= CASE WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
         END
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use the update command

```
update tsms_entry_exit set
delay = 
  case when id = 2 then 1
  else 0
end
where user_id = 1
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaa3b6/1)**